# Mount says host is down, but nmap says host is up

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Last night I added a mount point on my Ubuntu server and it worked fine using the below. After doing so I restarted the machine (which installed an update) and since that time I've been unable to mount the Samba share. When I try to mount I get error 112, host is down. I've checked all over the web and tried various ver= items with no success.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/Plex /NAS -o username=plex,password=****,vers=2.0 -vvv
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.1,unc=\\192.168.1.1\Plex,vers=2.0,user=plex,pass=****
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've also confirmed that the share is up using nmap.

```
nmap -p 445 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-23 17:37 EDT
Nmap scan report for cellspot.router (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.00032s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Also smbclient returns the folder I'm trying to mount:

```
sudo /usr/bin/smbclient -L 192.168.1.1
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.33]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
Family          Disk      My_Passport's Family in WD My Passport 259D
Plex            Disk      My_Passport's Plex in WD My Passport 259D
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NAS)

Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes' and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes' is set
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.33]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
NAS                  NAS
PLEX                 plex server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            PLEX
```

I created another VM box using the original image that I used for this box and was able to mount the same location with no issues, so definitely something related to the updated packages. Strangely, CIFS mounts to a windows system on the same box are working fine, so something about the router samba share.

finally, I was able to determine that one of the packages that was updated was samba. I have been unable to revert to an older version of samba, though I believe this is likely the issue. Any ideas what the issue could be?